# Fixed points of $ e^{x+1/x} = x$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

This particular question was one of the options in a question in amock test i am solving of masters in mathematics.

> Does $f(x) = e^{x+1/x}$ has unique fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$?

Attempt: the equation  can be simplified to $x+\frac{1}{x} = \log x$ and then $ x^2 +1 = x \log x $.

But I don't know the graph of $x \log x$ and hence can't solve the problem and don't know any other idea.

So, can you tell a elegant method to solve this question.

Thank you!!

Comment: You probably can't solve it directly (you'd need at the very least the Lambert $W$ function). On the other hand, you don't always need to find the solutions if you want to find the _number_ of solutions.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=e^{(x+1)/x}$? It's not true for $f(x)=e^{x+(1/x)}$. Is the question to prove that there exists a unique fixed point or to solve for the value of the fixed point?

Comment: Can $x$ be complex ?

Comment: @kccu no question is correct!!

Comment: @YvesDaoust No x lies in Reals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $x\ne0$, $f(x)>0$ and there can be no fixed-point in the negatives. Then for $x>0$, $f(x)\ge 1+x+\dfrac1x>x$ and there can be no fixed point in the negatives.

---

Note that if $x$ can take values in $\mathbb C$,

$$\overline{e^{x+1/x}}=e^{\bar x+1/\bar x}$$and the conjugate of a fixed point is also a fixed point !

Comment: (+1) $\mathbb{C}$ is always a neglected field ! :D

Comment: @Yves Daoust Why does $e^{x+1/x}$ has no fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$? Can you please explain that?

Comment: @Ben: read the first sentence in my post. Then read the second. And ponder both. The topic of these sentences is the answer to your question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust f(x) is not equal to $e^{1+1/x}$!

Comment: @Ben: what do you mean ?? You contradict your second sentence.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No I don't !!  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ben: I see. But why on Earth do you tell me that ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

as stated in the comments by @kccu $e^{x+\frac{1}{x}}$ has no fixed points (in $\mathbb{R}$, so maybe it's in $\mathbb{C}$ as stated in the answer of @Yves Daoust :P) so I assume it is $e^{\frac{x+1}{x}}$ .

Surely you have to search for it when $x>0$ , if you study the derivative of $$f(x) = e^{\frac{x+1}{x}}-x$$

what can you say about the **number** of fixed points? Now you need just to find a point where the function is positive and a point where the function is negative so that you can apply Bolzano's theorem to conclude.

Comment: why does $ e^{x+1/x}$ has no fixed points in Reals?

Comment: Please Dont assume it to be $e^{(x+1)/x}$!